# CSS: how to put element next to last line of text

Tags: html, css

I have a `span` with text inside and it has a `max-width` property.
Some times the text inside is bigger then the max width so the span is breaking lines. until here no problem.

But when the text breaks it looks like the element next to it doesnt go down aswell. here is an example

`<span> some text with fine width</span> <div> the div</div>`
that will output something like this:
`some text with fine width the div`

but when text is long it looks like that:

`<span> some text with more the max width</span> <div> the div</div>`

`some text with more the div
the max width`

and i want that to look like this:

`some text with more
the max width the div`

I manage to do this:

`some text with more
the max width         the div`

But i want that div to be just next to the last line of the text.
Is this possible via css?

Comment: Please add your current HTML and CSS to your question to enable us reproducing the issue.

Comment: Where is your `CSS` file ?

Answer (score 0):

In css add style for that element:

```
display: inline;
```

Answer (score 0):

### after pseudo-element

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you're searching for:

```
.stuff:after{
    content: "I am Groot.";
    display: inline-block;
    color: limegreen;
}
```

`:after` gets inserted just before the closing tag. Likewise `:before` just after the opening tag

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3m1ech2s/)**

Comment: Thats exectly what I need thanks! but one question. Does the conetent of the after must be hard coded in the css?

Comment: Unfortunately: yes. Usually it is not used for content, rather icons, or styling purposes. Also you can't enter html. What you could do to dynamically generate this is by adding it with php, javascript inside a `<style>` Tag